# Cardinality of Cartesian Product of sets proof or disproof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, and C be sets. For each of the following, either prove the
statement or give a counterexample.

#$A$ ≤ #$B$ $\Longrightarrow$ #$(A × C) ≤$ #$(B × C)$

I can prove that #$(A × C) =$ #$A$ $\cdot$ #$C$

Proof: Let $a \in A$. The number of pairs of the form $(a,b)$ where $b\in B$ is #$B$. Since there are #$B$ choices for $b$ for each of the #$A$ choices for $a \in A$, the number of elements in $A \times B$ is #$A$ $\cdot$ #$C$.

How does this help to prove or disprove the above statement? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the definition you can use of one set having a lesser cardinality than another?

Comment: @AndrewL you meant this: A set $A$ is said to have
cardinality less than or equal to than another set $B$ iff there exists a one-to-one function $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ ?

Comment: yes that's exactly the one I mean. This problem is much easier if you use that definition. For example, the hypothesis $|A| \leq |B|$ just means there is a one-to-one function from $A$ to $B$. At that point, all you need to do is find a one-to-one function from $A \times C$ to $B \times C$

Comment: @AndrewL I'm sorry but how can I find a one-to-one function from $A \times C$ to $B \times C$?

Comment: @hanamontana you are given the existence of a one to one function $f:A\to B$. Define a new function $g:A\times C\to B\times C$ by $g(a,c)=(f(a),c)$. Show that this function is one to one and you are done. However, be sure to consider the case when $C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

If $C = \emptyset$ then both $A \times C$ and $B \times C$ are empty too and so both have $0$ elements and the conclusion holds.

Otherwise let $f: A \to B$ be an injection. Then $g:=f \times 1: A \times C \to B \times C$ defined by $g(a,c)= (f(a),c)$ for all $a,b) \in A \times B$ is also an injection: suppose $g(a,c)=g(a’,c’)$ then $(f(a),c)= (f(a’),c’)$ by the definition of $g$ and so by the definition of ordered pairs $c=c’$ and also $f(a)=f(a’)$ and as $f$ is injective the latter implies $a=a’$. It follows that $(a,c)=(a’,c’)$ and we’re done.

So $ |(A \times C)| \le |(B \times C)|$ by the existence of $g$. (Considering the case $C=\emptyset$ separately is not really necessary here.)